# Create Procedure MySQL Error By No Description

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a basic procedure and build on that for a more complex procedure.

I've created a a basic script and receive an error with no description from PHPMyAdmin.

When run in HeidiSQL it shows as if its run correctly but states 0 queries run.

> /* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0
>   queries: 0.000 sec. */

This is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`%`

CREATE PROCEDURE t1()
BEGIN
    SELECT 'HELLO WORLD';
END

DELIMITER ;
```

Amy help to get me over this obstacle would be fantastic.

Comment: I'm not sure, but creating a procedure is not really running a query, is it? So maybe the output is just fine. Can you use the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to finish your Procedure Code with your Delimiter $$ and remove the Create statement of the procedure

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'

PROCEDURE t1()
BEGIN
    SELECT 'HELLO WORLD';
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Make sure your root user has permissions to run your procedure. If you get an error of permissions then try:

```
grant all on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

Comment: Thanks. The odd things is. Your code works in Heidi but doesn't work in PHPMyAdmin. Gives me an error like so...#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' to database 'information_schema'

Comment: You need to give permissions to root user, try this: 
    grant all on *.* to 'root'@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'password' with grant option;

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. Your last comment gave me a light-bulb. I was trying to create my procedure on the information_schema DB. Such a pleb. Thanks again.